# Multiple Image Upload in Magento2

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I created a multiple image uploader in magento2 everything was working fine but after some days it is giving this error

Uncaught ReferenceError: byteConvert is not defined

[image]

I don't know whats the issue.
Kinldy help thanks in advance

Comment: can you share that module?

Answer (score 1):

`byteConvert` is a one of function from `varien/js.js` library

This library loads via backend theme `vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/etc/view.xml`

```
<item type="file">Lib::varien/js.js</item>
```

You need to check why this library doesn't load on your backend page and solve the issue.

Comment: How to do that I was trying but dindnot find any solution !!

Comment: Please check `lib/web/legacy-build.min.js`. Is this file contains `byteConvert` function? Is this file loads in admin?

Comment: yes It contains the byteConvert function but still it is not working, I had try all the commands like cache:clean,cache:flush,setup:upgrade,di:compile,content:deploy etc

Comment: do you manged to fix this issue?

Comment: Facing the same issue again @WaqarAli